# Spectrum of an upper triangular infinite matrix

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there any theory about spectra of triangular infinite marices? If so, where could I read something about it?

Answer (score -1):

Any results about the spectra of triangular infinite matrices will be part of the spectral theory of linear operators. You can find it in any respectable functional analysis book. I found a book by Kreyszieg very approachable as I learned and my go-to reference is *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics* by Reed and Simon.